# Chrome not extending the width of my <td>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Good afternoon,

I am working on a report and the  width doesn't extend all the way over the screen. It works fine in IE but not in Chrome.

i will show you the way i have it now.

[incorrect version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLgOg.png)

The table tag doesn't extend all the way over.

In this next image, I added a width of 1600 to the element and it extends it correctly.

[Correct Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzoak.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your inline style "width=1600" doesnt have any percentage, vw, px, etc.  You need to define one of these inside style="..." CSS for browsers to know what your intended scale is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<style>table {width:100%;}</style>
```